# sleep doesn't work where it is desired to

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So, I am learning PyGame(beginner). And when I came across displaying text on the PyGame window, sleep didn't work as expected. As soon as I click any key, it was supposed to display the message, and then sleep for n seconds. But when I tried it, it slept for n seconds before displaying. Why is this happening and how should I fix it?

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def message_display(text):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text_surface, (400, 300))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)

gameDisplay.fill(white)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            message_display("Hello")

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. HELLO text appear immediately after I press a key.

Comment: Well, then how do I fix it? I am clueless. On one of my friend's laptop, it works as expected but on the other friend's laptop and mine, it first sleeps and then displays. It feels like some kind of synchronousity is happening just like in JS.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to happen on some systems due to some code optimizations causing synchronous behaviour. So, forcing it to complete its execution before heading to the next line seems to help. `threading` module helped in doing that.

```
def message(text):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text_surface, (400, 300))
    pygame.display.update()

def message_display(text):
    import threading

    p1 = threading.Thread(target=message, args=(text, ))

    # start the thread execution
    p1.start()

    # wait for it to complete to join it with the main program
    p1.join()

    time.sleep(5)
```